# set a limited length to element with contentEditable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a html `<div id = "a"></div>`
and js code:

```
const a = document.getElementById("a");
a.contentEditable = true;
```

and I want to set a max length of 30 to the a like input text. I've tried using

```
a.addEventListener("input",() => {
        if(a.innerText.length == 30) {
            a.contentEditable = false;
    }
```

but the outcome is not satisfing. It did stop the further input but also stoped me to edit a.

Answer (score 1):

I got the desired result by adding

```
a.innerText = a.innerText.slice(0,30);
```